# How to completion with function paren or arguments with Vim-lsp

Tags: vim, completion, language-server-protocol

With vim-lsp in java code, after type

```
System.out.printf
```

the following candidates appears:

```
printf(Locale l, String format, Object... args)
printf(String format, Object... args)
```

When I choose first of the candidates,

```
System.out.printf
```

but I want to get:

```
System.out.printf(l, format, args)
```

or

```
System.out.printf(,,)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Which language server are you using? Apache Camel? The behaviour you want is the behaviour I see with python (pyls), so it may be dependent on support in the language server.

Answer (score 0):

Try `:help vim-lsp-snippets`

For example [vim-lsp-ultisnips](https://github.com/thomasfaingnaert/vim-lsp-ultisnips) should get you what you want. It uses UltiSnips to let you cycle through the function arguments. The help page has options for other snippet engines.